# Changing SSH Default Port 22 to 444

Tags: linux, sshd

I have changed the default port number in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

When I start ssh service it does start,
but when I run `service sshd status`
it is stopped:

[image]

I am using CentOS 6.4.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm assuming your question is "why `sshd` keeps stopping after you've changed the port?"

CentOS has SELinux enabled by default, and `sshd` is one of the system services targeted by the SELinux policy. The policy restricts what the `sshd` process can do. So when you change `sshd` to a different port, you'll also need to add the appropriate label to the new port or else `sshd` will be prevented from using that port by SELinux.

To see the SELinux port labels: `semanage port -l`

To label port 444 for `sshd`, you'll need to do this:

```
semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 444
```

Then you can start `sshd` in a custom port:

```
service sshd start
```